# Postfix evaluation is very slow - optimization?

Tags: c++, postfix-notation

I've written a small expression evaluator. First, an expression is broken down to a postfix notation. Let's work with the following sample:

infix = "z*z+c"

My code creates a vector of strings in the following form: z, z, *, c, +

This question is not about Shunting Yard itself, it is about evaluating this postfix thing. I created another function:

```
Complex Evaluate(vector<string> post, Complex z, Complex c)
{
    vector<Complex> stack;
    Complex a1, a2, a3;
    for (int i = 0; i < post.size(); i++)
    {
        string s = post[i];
        if (IsNumber(s))
        {
            stack.push_back(stold(s));
        }
        else if (IsConst(s))
        {
            if (s == "pi")
            {
                stack.push_back(Pi);
            }
            else if (s == "e")
            {
                stack.push_back(E);
            }
            else if (s == "phi")
            {
                stack.push_back(2.61803398875);
            }
            else if (s == "eulergamma")
            {
                stack.push_back(EulerGamma);
            }
            else if (s == "i")
            {
                stack.push_back(I);
            }
        }
        else if (IsOperator(s))
        {
            if (s == "+")
            {
                a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
                a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
                stack.pop_back(); stack.pop_back();
                stack.push_back(a1 + a2);
            }
            else if (s == "-")
            {
                a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
                a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
                stack.pop_back(); stack.pop_back();
                stack.push_back(a2 - a1);
            }
            else if (s == "*")
            {
                a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
                a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
                stack.pop_back(); stack.pop_back();
                stack.push_back(a1 * a2);
            }
            else if (s == "/")
            {
                a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
                a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
                stack.pop_back(); stack.pop_back();
                stack.push_back(a2 / a1);
            }
            else if (s == "^")
            {
                a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
                a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
                stack.pop_back(); stack.pop_back();
                stack.push_back(pow(a2, a1));
            }
        }
        else if (IsFunction(s))
        {
            if (s == "sqrt")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = sqrt(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "sin")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = sin(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arcsin" || s == "asin")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = asin(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "sinc")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = sinc(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "cos")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = cos(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "cosc")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = cosc(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arccos" || s == "acos")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = acos(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "tan" || s == "tg")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = tan(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arctan" || s == "atan")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = atan(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "cot" || s == "cotg" || s == "cotan")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = cot(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "exp")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = exp(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "log" || s == "ln" || s == "lg")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = log(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "log10")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = log(stack[stack.size() - 1]) / Complex(log(10), 0);
            }
            else if (s == "log2")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = log(stack[stack.size() - 1]) / Complex(log(2), 0);
            }
            else if (s == "sinh" || s == "sh")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = sinh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arcsinh" || s == "asinh" || s == "ash")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = arcsinh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "cosh" || s == "ch")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = cosh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arccosh" || s == "acosh" || s == "ach")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = arccosh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "tanh" || s == "th" || s == "tgh")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = tanh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arctanh" || s == "atanh" || s == "ath")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = arctanh(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "cotanh" || s == "coth" || s == "ctgh" || s == "cth")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = coth(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "arccoth" || s == "acoth" || s == "acth")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = arccoth(stack[stack.size() - 1]);
            }
            else if (s == "lgamma" || s == "loggamma" || s == "logamma")
            {
                stack[stack.size() - 1] = lgamma(stack[stack.size() - 1], max(100000, (int)round(100000 * (abs(stack[stack.size() - 1]).Re))));
            }
        }
        else if (IsParam(s))
        {
            if (s == "z") { stack.push_back(z); }
            else if (s == "c") { stack.push_back(c); }
        }
    }
    return stack[stack.size() - 1];
}
```

So if I call Evaluate (postfix, 4, 2) I get correctly 4*4+2 = 18. However, I need to iterate through many complex points (third argument, c), so I need to execute this very quickly. When I do the following (to test the speed):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
{
    if ((i % 1000) == 0) { cout << i << endl; }
    result = Evaluate(postfix, 4, 2);
}
```

it takes tens of seconds to finish, which is very very slow. What is typical way of fast implementation of evaluation of postfix expressions? For the sake of completeness I also include Complex.h and Complex.cpp:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

class Complex
{
public:
    long double Re, Im;
    Complex(long double re = 0., long double im = 0.);
    friend Complex operator+(Complex, Complex);
    friend Complex operator+(long double, Complex);
    friend Complex operator+(Complex, long double);
    friend Complex operator-(Complex, Complex);
    friend Complex operator-(long double, Complex);
    friend Complex operator-(Complex, long double);
    Complex operator-() const &;
    friend Complex operator*(Complex, Complex);
    friend Complex operator*(long double, Complex);
    friend Complex operator*(Complex, long double);
    friend Complex operator/(Complex, Complex);
    friend Complex operator/(long double, Complex);
    friend Complex operator/(Complex, long double);
};

Complex operator+ (Complex c1, Complex c2);
Complex operator+ (long double r, Complex c);
Complex operator+ (Complex c, long double r);
Complex operator- (Complex c1, Complex c2);
Complex operator- (long double r, Complex c);
Complex operator- (Complex c, long double r);
Complex operator* (Complex c1, Complex c2);
Complex operator* (long double r, Complex c);
Complex operator* (Complex c, long double r);
Complex operator/ (Complex c1, Complex c2);
Complex operator/ (long double r, Complex c);
Complex operator/ (Complex c, long double r);

Complex arg(Complex c);
Complex abs(Complex c);
Complex sqrt(Complex c);
Complex re(Complex c);
Complex im(Complex c);
Complex cc(Complex c);
Complex exp(Complex c);
Complex log(Complex c);
Complex sinh(Complex c);
Complex arcsinh(Complex c);
Complex cosh(Complex c);
Complex arccosh(Complex c);
Complex tanh(Complex c);
Complex arctanh(Complex c);
Complex coth(Complex c);
Complex arccoth(Complex c);
Complex pow(Complex c, int n);
Complex pow(Complex c1, Complex c2);
Complex sin(Complex c);
Complex asin(Complex c);
Complex sinc(Complex c);
Complex cos(Complex c);
Complex acos(Complex c);
Complex cosc(Complex c);
Complex tan(Complex c);
Complex atan(Complex c);
Complex cot(Complex c);
Complex acot(Complex c);
Complex lgamma(Complex c, int n);

#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Complex.h"

const long double EulerGamma = 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992;
const Complex I = Complex(0, 1);

Complex::Complex(long double r, long double i)
{
    Re = r; Im = i;
}

Complex operator+ (Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    return Complex(c1.Re + c2.Re, c1.Im + c2.Im);
}

Complex operator+ (long double r, Complex c)
{
    return Complex(r + c.Re, c.Im);
}

Complex operator+ (Complex c, long double r)
{
    return Complex(r + c.Re, c.Im);
}

Complex operator- (Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    return Complex(c1.Re - c2.Re, c1.Im - c2.Im);
}

Complex operator- (long double r, Complex c)
{
    return Complex(r - c.Re, -c.Im);
}

Complex Complex::operator-() const &
{
    return Complex(- this->Re, - this->Im);
}

Complex operator- (Complex c, long double r)
{
    return Complex(c.Re - r, c.Im);
}

Complex operator* (Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    Complex result;
    result.Re = (c1.Re * c2.Re - c1.Im * c2.Im);
    result.Im = (c1.Re * c2.Im + c1.Im * c2.Re);
    return result;
}

Complex operator* (long double r, Complex c)
{
    return Complex(r*c.Re, r*c.Im);
}

Complex operator* (Complex c, long double r)
{
    return Complex(r*c.Re, r*c.Im);
}

Complex operator/ (Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    Complex result;
    result.Re = ((c1.Re * c2.Re + c1.Im * c2.Im) / (c2.Re*c2.Re + c2.Im*c2.Im));
    result.Im = ((c1.Im * c2.Re - c1.Re * c2.Im) / (c2.Re*c2.Re + c2.Im*c2.Im));
    return result;
}

Complex operator/ (long double r, Complex c)
{
    Complex result;
    result.Re = (r * c.Re / (c.Re*c.Re + c.Im*c.Im));
    result.Im = (-r * c.Im / (c.Re*c.Re + c.Im*c.Im));
    return result;
}

Complex operator/ (Complex c, long double r)
{
    return Complex(c.Re / r, c.Im / r);
}

Complex abs(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(sqrt(c.Re*c.Re + c.Im*c.Im), 0);
}

Complex arg(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(atan2(c.Im, c.Re), 0);
}

Complex sqrt(Complex c)
{
    long double r = abs(c).Re;
    long double phi = arg(c).Re;
    return Complex(sqrt(r)*cos(0.5*phi), sqrt(r)*sin(0.5*phi));
}

Complex re(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(c.Re, 0);
}

Complex im(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(0, c.Im);
}

Complex cc(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(c.Re, -c.Im);
}

Complex exp(Complex c)
{
    long double ex = exp(c.Re);
    return ex * Complex(cos(c.Im), sin(c.Im));
}

Complex log(Complex c)
{
    long double r = abs(c).Re;
    long double phi = atan2(c.Im, c.Re);
    return Complex(log(r), phi);
}

Complex sinh(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(sinh(c.Re)*cos(c.Im), cosh(c.Re)*sin(c.Im));
}

Complex arcsinh(Complex c)
{
    return log(c + sqrt(1 + c*c));
}

Complex cosh(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(cosh(c.Re)*cos(c.Im), sinh(c.Re)*sin(c.Im));
}

Complex arccosh(Complex c)
{
    return log(c + sqrt(c + 1)*sqrt(c - 1));
}

Complex tanh(Complex c)
{
    return sinh(c) / cosh(c);
}

Complex arctanh(Complex c)
{
    return 0.5*(log(1.0 + c) - log(1.0 - c));
}

Complex coth(Complex c)
{
    return cosh(c) / sinh(c);
}

Complex arccoth(Complex c)
{
    return 0.5*(log(1 + 1 / c) - log(1 - 1 / c));
}

Complex pow(Complex c, int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return Complex(1, 0);
    }
    else if (n == 1)
    {
        return c;
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
        return c*pow(c, n - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return Complex(1, 0) / pow(c, -n);
    }
}

Complex pow(Complex c1, Complex c2)
{
    if (abs(c2.Re - round(c2.Re)) > 1e-12 || c2.Im != 0)
    {
        return exp(c2*log(c1));
    }
    else
    {
        int n = round(c2.Re);
        return pow(c1, n);
    }
}

Complex sin(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(sin(c.Re)*cosh(c.Im), cos(c.Re)*sinh(c.Im));
}

Complex asin(Complex c)
{
    return -I*log(I*c + sqrt(abs(1 - c*c)) * exp(0.5*I*arg(1 - c*c)));
}

Complex sinc(Complex c)
{
    if (abs(c).Re > 0.01) { return sin(c) / c; }
    else { return 1 - c*c / 6 + c*c*c*c / 120; }
}

Complex cos(Complex c)
{
    return Complex(cos(c.Re)*cosh(c.Im), -sin(c.Re)*sinh(c.Im));
}

Complex acos(Complex c)
{
    return -I*log(c + I*sqrt(abs(1 - c*c)) * exp(0.5*I*arg(1 - c*c)));
}

Complex cosc(Complex c)
{
    if (abs(c).Re > 0.01) { return (1 - cos(c)) / c; }
    else { return c / 2 - c*c*c / 24 + c*c*c*c*c / 720; }
}

Complex tan(Complex c)
{
    return sin(c) / cos(c);
}

Complex atan(Complex c)
{
    return (1 / (2 * I))*log((I - c) / (I + c));
}

Complex cot(Complex c)
{
    return cos(c) / sin(c);
}

Complex acot(Complex c)
{
    return (1 / (2*I))*log((c + I) / (c - I));
}

Complex lgamma(Complex c, int n)
{
    Complex res = 0;
    res = -EulerGamma*c - log(c);
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        res = res + c / i - log(1 + c / i);
    }
    return res;
}
```

And additional functions like IsOperator are:

```
const vector<string> delimiters = { "(", ")", "[", "]", "{", "}" };
const vector<string> operators = { "+", "-", "/", "*", "^", "%" };
const vector<string> separators = { ",", ";", ":" };
const vector<string> params = { "x", "y", "z", "a", "b", "c", "w" };
const vector<string> constants = { "pi", "e", "eulergamma", "phi", "i" };
const Complex I = Complex(0, 1);
const long double EulerGamma = 0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992;
const long double Pi = 3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510;
const long double E = 2.71828182845904523536028747135266249775724709369995;

bool IsOperator(string isop)
{
    if (find(operators.begin(), operators.end(), isop) != operators.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool IsParam(string ispar)
{
    if (find(params.begin(), params.end(), ispar) != params.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool IsDelim(string isdel)
{
    if (find(delimiters.begin(), delimiters.end(), isdel) != delimiters.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool IsConst(string iscon)
{
    if (find(constants.begin(), constants.end(), iscon) != constants.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool IsSeparator(string issep)
{
    if (find(separators.begin(), separators.end(), issep) != separators.end())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool LeftPar(string isleftpar)
{
    if (isleftpar == "(" || isleftpar == "[" || isleftpar == "{") { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

bool RightPar(string isrightpar)
{
    if (isrightpar == ")" || isrightpar == "]" || isrightpar == "}") { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}

bool IsFunction(string isfun)
{
    if (!IsNumber(isfun) && !IsParam(isfun) && !IsConst(isfun) && !IsDelim(isfun) && !IsSeparator(isfun) && !IsOperator(isfun))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Basically, my question is: why is it taking so long? Where is the bottleneck? How else could it be implemented, besides a bunch of if else (the code must somehow recognize a number, a variable, a function etc.)? I don't need you to run this code, I just want someone to take a look at it and point out what can be done better (besides importing an external library for this kind of things). Thanks.

P.S.: I will want to use functions such as sin, cos, exp, pow, ... so I must have that second part with lot of functions. But as far as I can tell, if else (IsFunction) won't execute if it finds it's z, c, or number beforehand.

Comment: That is a huge mess of spaghetti code. If you write clearer code inefficiencies will be easier to spot and fix and maybe the optimizer will properly understand your code and generate efficient instructions. Additionally the question "Where is the bottleneck" is not a question for stackoverflow, that's what profilers are for. Casually looking over the code I notices you are copying strings unnecessarily in for example `IsOperator`, but without a profiler it's hard to tell if that is the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: Also why didn't you just use [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex)? It would have saved you so much code.

Comment: I don't know where to type this comment, but: be honest with me guys, is it possible to boost speed of such evaluation to be able to perform milions of evaluations within reasonable time units (fractions of seconds)? In it's current state, with lookup tables for operators and constants, it still takes a few seconds to repeat the evaluation 500,000 times. I need that WAY faster. To compare, if I hardcode a function to the source code, it evaluates ~ten times faster. Is such speedup possible?

Comment: Did you fix the issues that people pointed out? Are you sure all the things your code is doing are absolutely necessary? Have you checked if you can do some caching or use threads? Did you use a profiler to check which part is the bottleneck? Have you even turned on optimizations? Getting those 500000 operations done in under a second seems reasonable on a modern CPU.

Comment: I can't get working that lookup table for functions: I don't know what to type to the second argument of unordered_map (see my comment lower). Although I'm using lookup table for constants and operators now, even if the evaluated expression is numeric without functions, it is still slow. And I don't know how to effectively implement that very important check: if character is "z" then use the second argument and if it's "c" then use the third, it still relies on the string comparison. Edit: I got it working with using type: typedef Complex(*fun)(const Complex& c); (but it's still slow)

Answer (score 3):

There is no point calling `IsOperator` and then comparing against each of the operators in turn.  The problem is that at the moment, you are doing a *huge* number of string comparisons.  Create a bunch of functions for each of the functions, constants, and operators.  Have a `std::unordered_map` which maps from a string to the appropriate function.  Look the function up in the map, and call the function.

Something like:

```
typedef void (*function)(std::stack<Complex>& stack, const Complex& z,
                                                     const Complex& c);

void plus(std::stack<Complex>& stack, const Complex& , const Complex& )
{
    const auto a1 = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    const auto a2 = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    stack.push( a1+a2 );
}

const static std::unordered_map<std::string, function> lookup_table
    { {"+",plus}, ... };

Complex Evaluate(const std::vector<string>& post, const Complex& z,
                                                  const Complex& c)
{
    std::stack<Complex> stack;
    for (const auto& s : post)
    {
        const auto it = lookup_table.find(s);
        if (it != lookup_table.end())
        {
            (it->second)(stack, z, c);
        }
        else if (IsNumber(s))
        {
            stack.push_back(stold(s));
        }
        else
        {
            // bad input
        }
     }
     ....
```

You could make this a little slicker by creating an `Evaluator` class which holds the stack and params, and then making the functions be member functions of that.  Then your map would be of 'pointers-to-member-function', and you would invoke with `(evaluator->*(it-second))()`.

Note that I have also switched to using `std::stack`, and passing everything by reference.  That will be particularly helpful for the `post` argument.

Comment: I'd even consider suggesting _all_ functions should have the same signature, namely `void (*)(std::stack<std::complex>&)`. Even `pi` can be a function that way: pop 0, push 1.

Comment: I can't get that unordered map working, there is an error that plus is ambiguous....

Comment: Oh and also that plus routine shows errors everywhere "stack<Complex> &stack incomplete type is not allowed"

Comment: @user16320  Have you included `<stack>`?

Comment: @MSalters : All the functions *must* have the same signature, otherwise you can't put them in the map.  You need to pass in z and c so that the parameter invocation functions have them to hand. (hence my suggestion of an `Evaluator` class.

Comment: @user16320 : `plus` is probably ambiguous because you've got a wretched `using namespace std;`, so you are picking up the standard `plus` by accident.  I suggest a) removing that global using statement; b) renaming the `plus` function to something unique.  (Perhaps `Plus`).

Comment: @MartinBonner: You can have 3 maps, for constants, unary functions and binary functions. Of course, that still needs some parsing to figure out whether you want the unary `-` or binary `-`.

Comment: @MSalters : You *could*.  That would involve more lookups, and I can't see why you would want different maps for different arity functions.  unary/binary `-` has to have been sorted out at the parsing stage doesn't it?

Comment: @MartinBonner: True, but that also shows a fundamental issue with this implementation. If I would implement this, in parsing I'd replace `"-"` with enum value `Token::UnaryMinus` or `Token::BinaryMinus`. In evaluation I won't need a map, an array will work.

Comment: @MSalters : Ooo!  Good plan!  Also convert constants to `double` (or `Complex`) - and do the named constants at parse time.  You'd probably want a parallel array of constants, and you just extract the relevant one for `Token::Constant`.  In fact, at that point, one could just use a big switch statement ...

Comment: Why can't I do that plus thing with vector? It doesn't raise any errors if I do it with vector<Complex> and use pop_back instead of pop, last instead of top and push_back instead of push. And I have included <stack>

Comment: And so the next idea would be using this? const static unordered_map<string, function> lookup_table_func
{ { "sin", Sin },... }; When I try that it says that "cannot convert from 'initializer list' to std::unordered_map" blahblahblah

Answer (score 2):

```
Complex Evaluate(vector<string> post, Complex z, Complex c)
{
```

All of these parameters gets passed by value. Which means that every call to `Evaluate()` duplicates the entire `post` vector, for no useful reason, whatsoever. The entire vector. Every string in the vector. Additionally the two `Complex` classes get duplicated as well. This is a total waste of electrons.

A good start is by passing all parameters by reference:

```
Complex Evaluate(const vector<string> &post, const Complex &z, const Complex &c)
```

Now let's look at the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < post.size(); i++)
{
    string s = post[i];
```

A more modern compiler is likely to optimize the call to `size()`, and not have to call it on each iteration, by correctly analyzing that `post` never changes. Less likely is that the compiler is smart enough to completely optimize-away the copy-construction.

One common underlying reason for this code's inefficiency is that you need to better understand how objects work in C++. This is copy-constructing a completely new object, without any good reason to do so. Even, at best, this is a potential waste of electrons.

```
for (const auto &s:post)
```

Now, the compiler has all it needs to generate the most efficient loop code, and use an alias reference for the current element inside the loop, with 0% penalty.

```
           a1 = stack[stack.size() - 1];
           a2 = stack[stack.size() - 2];
```

These two objects get declared at the beginning of the function. And every time, here, an assignment operator requires making a copy of an existing object (from `stack`) and place it into `a1` (and `a2`). Again, nothing useful comes from that. I'd estimate low-to-average chance that the compiler can understand that the initial declarations of `a1` and `a2` are a waste, and the assignment operator can be optimized away here. Instead of declaring `a1` and `a2`:

```
           auto e=stack.end();
           const auto &a1 = *--e;
           const auto &a2 = *--e;
```

This should be enough to let the compiler replace all that waste of electrons from uselessly copying the objects around in memory, with a simple calculation of two memory addresses.

```
        else if (s == "phi")

        else if (s == "eulergamma")

        if (s == "sqrt")

        else if (s == "sin")
```

A metric ton of string comparisons.

All of these should be replaced by a static `unordered_map` lookup table, mapping keywords to lambdas and properly initialized, up front. The lambdas take a few parameters, such as the `stack`, and perform the necessary calculations. You'll have to do `IsNumber()`, etc..., as the first order of business, looks to me like this will be the most frequent hit, and if it fails, fall back to using the lookup map for the remaining operations.

This is going to replace a major waste of electrons from executing a metric ton of string comparisons, with a single hashed lookup, and an indirect call via a function pointer.

Comment: If the `Complex` class is just 2 doubles, then passing by value may be superior to involving an indirection operation

Comment: *Personally* I wouldn't bother with the `auto e` optimization, particularly when pushing on the stack is either `*e++ = ...` or `stack.push_back(...)` depending. (And you may or may not need the `.pop_back` calls.) ... At least I wouldn't bother until the profiler told me I needed to.  The other changes are either obvious (hash map) or just general code cleanliness (avoid copies).

Comment: I have a question about that auto e thing...So before the main for cycle I define: auto e=stack.end(); const auto &a1 = *--e; const auto &a2 = *--e; but then how do I destroy last two elements in the stack and add new element a1+a2 there? Either I pop_back twice, in which case those numbers no longer exist, or I add it beforehand, but then I can't pop it immediately afterwards, because I destroy it.

Comment: @user16320: You calculate `e` inside each if clause (or actually, inside each function).  As to pop_back, you need `a1 = *--e; a2 = *--e; *e++ = a1+a2; stack.pop_back();`  You only need *one* pop_back, because you reuse the other one to store the result.

Answer (score 1):

As user16320 said, the likely cause of inefficiency is the copying of the arguments - you do this all over the place, including Evaluate where post, z and c are copies, and then calls like cos() and the operators all copy the Complex objects. Although not big, creating and destroying them will slow everything down. Use constant refs instead of passing by Vale. Use a profiler to check this is the issue.

Comment: user16320 is the OP.